# Can I buy TF2 items with my credit card?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

Well this morning, I was going to buy a mann.co supply crate key. Which costs £1.49. But when I try to buy it, it only lets me pay with steam wallet. I mean I could add some money to it, but the minimum is £4.00, and I only need £1.49. And I'm not willing to spend £4 pound. Anyways is there a way I can change the payment method to credit card and not steam wallet? It just selects steam wallet automaticlly and I can't change the payment method to credit card, or anything els. Please help.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but whenever you go to buy a game, if you have anything in your Steam wallet it automatically applies that towards that purchase (at least in the US version).  So if you plan on buying another game at some point it's not a loss at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three or so ways to get credit into the Steam Wallet:

- topping it up with your credit card,
- buying Steam Wallet codes in physical stores, and
- selling marketable items from any participating Steam game (including Steam Trading Cards and Booster Packs) on the Steam Market.

You *must*, however, use Steam Wallet credit to do microtransactions through Steam; TF2 does not allow you to buy items otherwise. Other games, such as Realm of the Mad God, might allow you to use in-game premium currency to achieve the same result; that's not any better, however.

Considering that you may use your Steam Wallet credit as a source for game purchases (even if your Steam Wallet funds don't cover your entire purchase) and that this credit is valid towards any micro-transaction of participating games, I don't think it's *so* bad.

If you want, we have a question on [how to spend eur 5 exactly in the Mann Co. store](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/25366/23). Maybe the same items total up 4 pounds?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  You can only use Steam Credit to buy Mann Co. Supply items.  You cannot charge it directly to your credit card.

The good news is you can buy anything on Steam with Steam Credit, so if you add a little more than you need to your account, it will be available there for your next game or item purchase.

---

Alternatively, if you have a bunch of Steam cards you don't want, you could just sell them for the requisite Steam Credit, and cut out having to pay entirely.  This'll take awhile, and depends on how much people are willing to pay for your cards, but it could save you that much money.

Comment: Bonus solution: re-evaluate how much you need virtual vanity items.

Comment: Also note that when adding funds using a new credit card it may lock you out of the account for a week.  See [here](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/7/864978109875715939/).

Comment: @Kotekzot This is also a good answer. A key will only get you one item anyway, and you have no way of knowing if it'll be a strange weapon, a hat, or some pile of useless strange parts.